# Model Validation for internal only used model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model that is only used internally by python in views. There is no form involved. It looks like this

```
class ShareLink(models.Model):

    from_share = models.ForeignKey(Share, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_share')
    to_share = models.ForeignKey(Share, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_share')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    mode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SHARE_LINK_MODE_CHOICES, default=1)

    class Meta:

        unique_together = ('from_share', 'to_share', 'mode', 'active')

    def clean(self):
        ret = super(ShareLink, self).clean()
        return ret
```

Depending on the colum mode i have some restrictions. eg the creator must be the creator of from_share and so on. So basically what would be done in the clean() of the model. But this is only called if a ModelForm is involved. But I do not have one as this model is only used internaly. What is the best way to validate my model ? Any advice

Comment: So you are going to create instances of ShareLink in python code if I understand correctly? Or what do you mean by 'internally'?

Comment: yes only in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implementing `clean()` method in model, you can call `full_clean()` method in view before saving instance to perform validations (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)):

```
sharelink = ShareLink()
try:
    sharelink.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
    # Display them to a user, or handle them programmatically.
    pass
sharelink.save()
```

Comment: Most of the time I am using .objects.create (....) to create new Objects. I read another Proposal to use a Mixin like class ShareLink(ValidatorMixin, models.Model): and then overwrite the save method in this mixin. But comments suggested that this might cause problems. The approach with objects.create(...) seems to be a little controversal.